# batch script to read a file containing path-to-dir, and get the latest file,read the last line from the file and print

Tags: batch-file

Apologies for the very long title, i was wondering if some one could help me out with this.

What I'm trying to do is read a file which contains, say, 10 different directory paths, get the latest file in that directory and read the last line from that file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo Host: %host%
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%I in (C:\temp\servers.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%I
    echo Path-to-File: %%I
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%X in ('dir "%%I" /OD /B')  do (
    set newest=%%X
    )
    echo %newest%
    )
```

Here is the output:

```
Host: Windows7
Path-to-File: \\Windows7\C$\direct\log\direct
ECHO is off.
Path-to-File: \\Windows7\C$\temp
ECHO is off.
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Where you have `echo %newest%` try changing it to `echo !newest!` and see whether that makes any difference.

Comment: wow..that worked..thanks a ton rojo..if this was reddit, i would have given u reddit gold!! just curious what is the difference..sorry i'm completely new to batch scripting.

Comment: In a cmd prompt window, type `help set` and space bar four or five times until you get to the "Delayed environment variable expansion" section.

Comment: The HELP system describes the difference. Type `HELP SET` from the command prompt and start reading about half-way through with the paragraph that begins "Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added..."

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I am somewhat confused by your description. The Batch file below was written in accordance with I understood about your requirement.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Host: %COMPUTERNAME%

rem Process the file with the paths:
for /F "delims=" %%I in (C:\temp\servers.txt) do (
   echo Path-to-File: %%I
   rem Get the newest file in this directory
   for /F "delims=" %%X in ('dir "%%I" /OD /B') do (
      set "newest=%%~X"
   )
   echo Newest-File: !newest!
   rem Read the last line from this file
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("!newest!") do (
      set "lastLine=%%L"
   )
   echo Last-Line: !lastLine!
)
```

I hope it helps...

Antonio